# How to convert a Sitecore update package to .zip package?

Tags: sitecore

In my continuos integration pipeline, I am trying to use Sitecore powershell extensions to create anti package from Sitecore courier generated .update package. I have found a [blog](http://xcentium.com/blog/2015/11/10/sitecore-and-powershell)

which tells how to create an anti .zip package but it requires a .zip package and the related xml file.How do I get a .zip package from Sitecore courier? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the blog post are talking about a package created by the Sitecore Package Designer, which generates a .zip file. This is probably what you are looking for.

The .update package file you are referring to might be generated by Team Development for Sitecore(?) or is a Sitecore update?
An .update package is actually a zip archive, so you can just rename the file from .update to .zip and you will see it as a zip archive.

Comment: I want to pass the generated package to Sitecore rocks and create an anti package out of this.. via powershell scripts.. if that is possible! is that possible?

Comment: Also, since the folder structure is different for a .update package and a .zip package, I am not able to use my .update packages to create anti .update packages using Sitecore Rocks for example. Sitecore rocks accepts only a .zip package. Renaming the .update file to .zip is not working in this case.